# Pass value using pipe symbol to a powershell Start-Process command, from cmd window

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I have a batch script like below. I want to call this script from a terminal window `(cmd)`, by running it using `powershell` `Start-Process` command *(Doing this in Azure ARM Template)*.
I want to pass the `INPUT` value while calling the script, probably by using a pipe symbol.

Not able to pass the `INPUT` value through pipe symbol to a `Start-Process` command.
Am I missing something?
How can I achieve this *(without any modifications to this batch file)*?

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type yes or no: %=%

echo[
echo actually typed %INPUT%

IF "%INPUT%"=="n" goto :CLICKEDNO
IF "%INPUT%"=="N" goto :CLICKEDNO
IF "%INPUT%"=="NO" goto :CLICKEDNO
IF "%INPUT%"=="no" goto :CLICKEDNO
IF "%INPUT%"=="No" goto :CLICKEDNO
IF "%INPUT%"=="yes" goto :CLICKEDYES
IF "%INPUT%"=="Yes" goto :CLICKEDYES
IF "%INPUT%"=="Y" goto :CLICKEDYES
IF "%INPUT%"=="y" goto :CLICKEDYES

:CLICKEDYES
echo Typed yes
goto :eof

:CLICKEDNO
echo Typed no
goto :eof

echo end of file
```

---

Even though I am trying to pass the value "no", it is printing "yes".

Below are some of the commands that I have tried.

1. `echo no | powershell Set-Location -Path C:\CAP\CAP-Installer ; Start-Process -NoNewWindow  .\test.bat`
2. `echo no | powershell Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\CAP\CAP-Installer\test.bat`

   Output for the comands 1 and 2:

   ```
   Type yes or no:
   actually typed no
   Typed yes
   ```
3. `powershell -Command "echo no | Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\CAP\CAP-Installer\test.bat"`
4. `echo no | powershell -Command "$input | Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\CAP\CAP-Installer\test.bat"`

   Output for the comands 3 and 4:

   ```
   Type yes or no: Start-Process : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command
   either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its
   properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
   At line:1 char:11
   + echo no | Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\CAP ...
   +           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (no:PSObject) [Start-Process], Paramet
      erBindingException
       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Start
      ProcessCommand


   C:\Users\CAP-VM>

   actually typed
   Typed yes

   C:\Users\CAP-VM>
   ```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks is advance.

Comment: I understand there are other items you need to run via powershell, but that still does not mean you need to run this via powershell when you can just call it directly as per my answer below.

Comment: Where do you think execution will land when you type in `maybe`?

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to do a match for each case. use `if /i` to match case insensitive, we also need to use `%1` to specify :

```
@echo off

echo Type Yes/no & set /P "in=%1"

if /i "%in%" == "n" goto :no
if /i "%in%" == "no" goto :no
if /i "%in%" == "y" goto :yes
if /i "%in%" == "yes" goto :yes

:yes
echo Typed yes
goto :eof

:no
echo Typed no
goto :eof
```

obviously it is not even needed to `set` anything, so this is a better option:

```
@echo off

if /i "%~1" == "n" goto :no
if /i "%~1" == "no" goto :no
if /i "%~1" == "y" goto :yes
if /i "%~1" == "yes" goto :yes

:yes
echo Typed yes
goto :eof

:no
echo Typed no
goto :eof
```

and Even better, use `choice` to make choices instead of using `if`

```
@echo off
choice /c yn /m "yes/no"
if not "%errorlevel%" equ "0" goto _opt%errorlevel%
exit /b 0
:_opt1
echo You chose Yes
goto :EOF

:_opt2
echo You chose No
goto :EOF
```

You can simply run it directly from `cmd` and not via `cmd` to call `powershell` to run a `batch-file` which runs in `cmd`. Much simpler:

```
echo yes|"C:\CAP\CAP-Installer\test.bat"
```

If you really need to use it via `powershell` send it as a paramater:

```
powershell Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\CAP\CAP-Installer\test.bat yes
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The part about using `/i` for checking case insensitivity helps. Thank you. However, I would still like to know if it is possible to call powershell from cmd to run a batch-file with a value passed to it.

Comment: no it won't do `powershell Start-Process -NoNewWindow -FilePath C:\CAP\CAP-Installer\test.bat yes` instead.

Comment: I suppose, based upon example **1.** of the question, i.e. `test.bat` is in the current directory, and a the required working directory is `C:\CAP\CAP-Installer`, I would suggest perhaps, `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -ArgumentList 'N' -FilePath '.\test.bat' -NoNewWindow -WorkingDirectory 'C:\CAP\CAP-Installer'" -NoLogo -NoProfile`. or `%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command "Start-Process -ArgumentList 'Y' -FilePath '.\test.bat' -NoNewWindow -WorkingDirectory 'C:\CAP\CAP-Installer'" -NoLogo -NoProfile`.